# Java HashSet<> : Return false if HashSet contains values other than specified

Tags: java, hashset

So I extracted a List of Strings e.g {"ADD","DEL","CHG","DEL","NA","ADD","BLAH","YAK",.... } from JSON Request and passed them onto a hashset to avoid duplicates.
How do I get my function to return false if the HashSet has anything else other than "ADD" or "NA" or both ?
Any Help Appreciated.

Update:
In my code, I just added a NOT condition around all those values that I can possibly think of that I do not require.I need a more effective solution.

Also: My true() condition is that ADD must present at all times while NA is optional.No other values must be present other than the mandatory "ADD" and the optional "NA" .
eg:

1. {ADD} returns true
2. {ADD,NA} return true
3. {ADD,DEL} returns false
4. {DEL,YAK} return false, etc.

The below snippet doesn't have this check and i am looking for the best solution with least verbosity.

Here's the snippet. The List of Strings are passed as an argument to isAddOrNa().

```
private boolean isAddOrNa(List<AllActions> allActions) {
    Set<String> actions = new HashSet<>();
    for (com.demo.Action action : allActions) {
        actions.add(action.getName());
    }
    return ((actions.size() <= 2) && (actions.contains("ADD") || actions.contains("NA"))) &&
            !(actions.contains("DEL") || actions.contains("CHG") || actions.contains("BLAH") || actions.contains("YAK"));
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Both or "both"?

Comment: "both" as in both of the values.

Comment: If your goal was to confuse, you've definitely succeeded...

Comment: Sorry, too little too late, but I have removed the quotes out of "both" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean isAddOrNa(List<AllActions> allActions) {
    Set<String> actions = new HashSet<>();
    for (com.demo.Action action : allActions) {
        actions.add(action.getName());
    }
    return actions.contains("ADD") && ((actions.contains("NA") && actions.size() ==2) || (!actions.contains("NA") && actions.size() ==1));
}
```

Minimized the conditions. Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, this condition will return false if allActions contain only "ADD". Also , ||(!actions.contains("NA") && actions.size() ==1))   will return true if allActions contain other values like DEL. Lots of problems in this logic.

Comment: I tested it. It works. My solution checks that it mush contain "ADD" and  if hashset contains "NA" then it's size must be 2 otherwise size will be 1.

Comment: Sorry, i misintepretated and misplaced the brackets after i pasted this in my IDE to test. This works , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
 String add= "ADD";
 String NA ="NA"
 final Set<String> Strings = Sets.newHashSet("ADD","DEL","CHG","DEL","NA","ADD","BLAH","YAK");

 if (!((Strings .contains(add))||(Strings .contains(NA )))){
 return false;
 }
```

according to ur reuirement,

```
if(String.contains(add)){
    if(String.contains(NA)){
        return true;
          }
     }
 return false;
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't give you this update earlier. My true() condition is that ADD must present at all times while NA is optional.No other values must be present other than the mandatory "ADD" and the optional "NA". The above condtion will return true if only "NA" is present which is not expected.

Comment: if NA is optional then u can have condition for only 'ADD'. if(!String.contains(add)){ return false;}

Comment: What i meant was that {ADD,NA} can be true, {ADD} can be true, but {ADD,DEL} or {ADD,YAK} or {DEL,YAK} will be a false.

Comment: Not only ADD must be present all the time, but also any other values along with ADD (other than NA) should return false.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you want a validation method for your `Set`. If the list from JSON was just { "ADD", "NA", "ADD" }, for example, it would be fine and your method should return true. If there are other values in the list, like in the example in the question, it should return false.

It’s not complicated when you know how:

```
private static boolean setHasOnlySpecifiedValues(
        Set<String> specifiedValues, Set<String> setToCheck) {
    // we check setToCheck by removing specifiedValues and seeing if there are any
    // values left: however, the caller may be surprised if we remove elements from
    // the set passed to us, so work on a copy instead
    Set<String> workingCopy = new HashSet<>(setToCheck);
    workingCopy.removeAll(specifiedValues);
    if (workingCopy.isEmpty()) { // there were only specified values
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("The set contained other values: " + workingCopy);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `removeAll` method in the Java collections framework is one of the so-called set operations (not because it works on sets, it works on lists and maps too). You may think of it as an implementation of the set difference operation.

Lets try the method out:

```
    List<String> fromJson 
            = Arrays.asList("ADD", "DEL", "CHG", "DEL", "NA", "ADD", "BLAH", "YAK");
    Set<String> setToCheck = new HashSet<>(fromJson);
    Set<String> specifiedValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("ADD", "NA"));
    // or in Java 9: Set<String> specifiedValues = Set.of("ADD", "NA");

    boolean ok = setHasOnlySpecifiedValues(specifiedValues, setToCheck);
    System.out.println("The result of the check is: " + ok);
```

This prints:

```
The set contained other values: [YAK, CHG, DEL, BLAH]
The result of the check is: false
```

In the end you probably don’t want the `System.out.println()` statement inside the checking method. I put it there for now so you can see the exact result of `removeAll()`.

Comment: My true() condition is that ADD must present at all times while NA is optional.No other values must be present other than the mandatory "ADD" and the optional "NA" . Could you please update how can we add this check in your solution ?

Comment: Just add the condition `setToCheck.contains("ADD")`. @sahilsahadevan

Answer (score 0):

if(hashSet.contains("ADD")||(hashset.contains("NA"))
   return false;

Use it thanks

Comment: My true() condition is that ADD must present at all times while NA is optional.No other values must be present other than the mandatory "ADD" and the optional "NA". The above condtion will return true if only "NA" is present which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem is to check for anything other that "NA" and "ADD" in the input set. That can be achieved by adding the input set with your validation set, while doing so you will get false in case no new element is found in the input set and true otherwise :

```
            import java.util.HashSet;
            import java.util.Set;

            public class HashSetTheory {

                public static void main(String args[]){

                    String[] sourceData = {"ADD","DEL","CHG","DEL","NA","ADD","BLAH","YAK" }; // Output is false
                    //String[] sourceData = {"ADD","ADD","ADD","NA","NA","ADD","NA","ADD" };  // Output is true
                    //String[] sourceData = {"ADD","ADD","ADD" };  // Output is true
                    //String[] sourceData = { };  // Output is false
                    //String[] sourceData = { "NA" , "Something"};  // Output is false

                    Set<String> myRepo = new HashSet<>();

                    // Populating the set with input data
                    for(String data : sourceData){
                        myRepo.add(data);
                    }

                    Set<String> check = new HashSet<>();
                    check.add("NA");
                    check.add("ADD");

                    System.out.println("==>" + validateData(myRepo,check) );

                }

                public static boolean validateData(Set<String> myRepo,Set<String> check){
                    boolean retVal = true;

                    if(myRepo.size()==0){
                        return false;
                    }

                    for (String s : myRepo) {
                        // Adding an element in set returns false if it already exists
                        if(check.add(s)){
                            //This check is pass only if the set has some new item in it
                            retVal = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return retVal;
                } 

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is beyond me how large your List was or what your intentions are but from what you have provided, a naive solution off the top of my head would be to do 3 searches on the HashSet for those selected words with a counter keeping track of the hits. then compare that against size() of the HashSet.

Comment: Please read [answer].  Do not post comments as answers just because you do not have the necessary rep yet.  Do not abuse the system.

Comment: Beg to differ, @JimGarrison. This does answer the question as asked. It furthermore doesn’t give away code for free, which the OP frankly wouldn’t deserve with so little effort demonstrated. We can discuss whether this is the best solution to the problem, but the format of the answer is to my liking.