# Java HashSet contains value other than the intended one, not predefined value

Tags: java, contains, hashset

I looked at this forum answer [Java HashSet<> : Return false if HashSet contains values other than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426742/java-hashset-return-false-if-hashset-contains-values-other-than-specified)

However in this forum answer, the options are  predefined, for me it is not.

I read from a Web Table and the other city name can be anything.

//ToDo: If set contains anything other than Seattle, make it fail

```
public void cityTest() {
    Set<String> citySet = new HashSet<>();
    citySet.add("Seattle");
    citySet.add("Boston");

    //Case 1: Check size and if it is more than 1 we know we got more than 1 city name
    if (citySet.size() > 1) {
        Assert.fail("Expected only Seattle but found more than 1 city");
    }

    //Case 2: See if the set contains any other city name than Seattle
    if (citySet.contains("Seattle") && (!(citySet.contains("Seattle")))) { // This does not work
    Assert.fail("Expected only Seattle but found more than 1 city");
}
    }
}
```

Question: What logic can I use for case 2?

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Remove Seattle from the set and see if it still has any elements.

Comment: `if (citySet.contains("Seattle") && (!(citySet.contains("Seattle"))))` is exactly equivalent to `if it is raining and also it is not raining...`

Comment: Also `(!(citySet.contains("Seattle")))` these parenthesis do nothing but make your code a lot harder to read... `!citySet.contains("Seattle")` is all you need to negate (even though the logic here is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second case your saying if city set contains Seattle and does not contain Seattle
that will never return true.
you could say if city set contains Seattle and size is greater than 1, that would return true if there is more cities.

Comment: Thanks yes, I can use that logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple, try this

```
if (citySet.size() > 1 || !citySet.contains("Seattle")) {
    Assert.fail("Expected only Seattle but found more than 1 city");
}
```

thanks